# Get the next element by selecting element with a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a live search and a list element is given a class of `hover` I am then trying to get the next li element after the hover class upon pressing the down arrow and adding the `hover` class to that element. Here is what I have:

```
    if(e.keyCode == 40){
        var current = results.find('li.hover');
        current.removeClass();
        current.parent().next('li').addClass('hover');
        return false;
    }
```

It just will not add a class to the next element. It finds the current class just fine. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Appreciate it!

Comment: Can we see the HTML structure, please?

Comment: What is the value of `results`?

Comment: `current.next('li').addClass('hover');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `e.which`, not `e.keyCode`. jQuery normalizes the property (IE doesn't support `e.keyCode`):

```
if(e.which == 40){
```

As for your selector, try this:

```
results.find('li.hover').removeClass().next('li').addClass('hover')
```

`.next()` looks for the next sibling matching the selector, so there is no need to call `.parent()`.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the LI.hover, after that you go to the parent (which is the UL) and then select the next LI after the UL.

Change this:

```
current.parent().next('li').addClass('hover');
```

To:

```
current.next('li').addClass('hover');
```

Answer (score 0):

`current.parent().next('li')` is probably not doing what you want.

Since `current` is a jQuery object of `li` tags, I assume that it's parent is a `ul` tag.   If that's the case, then `next('li')` is looking for a first sibling of the `ul` tag that's an `li` tag which it will never find.

It's unclear to me which `li` you want to add the hover class to so I'm not sure exactly what to recommend to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Do not you just want to do that :

```
if(e.keyCode == 40){
    var current = results.find('li.hover');
    current.removeClass();
    current.next('li').addClass('hover');
    return false;
}
```

without *parent()* ?

Answer (score 0):

current.nextSibling should refer to the next li element in the list